# Height of <body> element in HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my code:
The header is in fixed position, and I add a margin and padding zero to body

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="center"></div>
        <div id="a"></div>
    </div>
</body>


body {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#content{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
}


#a{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Now I want to ask, why is body 60px lower. It should not body always be the top 0? 
Here is a picture of this:

[body height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lco1m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin-top` in your `#content` is pushing the body down. Please read more on [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

[image]